# Display separate tabs for public, private & hidden groups in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to wordpress & buddypress. I wanted to know how can I display separate tabs for public,private & hidden groups for users in the groups section, where all groups are displayed. There is a function `bp_get_total_group_count()` for getting the total group count for a particular user, but no function to determine which type of group it is (i.e **public**, **private** or **hidden**). Might have to use some `apply_filter` thing, but am not sure.

Please help.

I can provide you with the code, if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after some digging. Here it is:
The process is for separately showing a private group, follow the same for public and hidden.

**1.** In bp-groups/bp-groups-template.php, under the function bp_has_groups, add the line:

elseif ( 'anything' == $bp->current_action ) {
        $type = 'anything'; }

**2.** In bp-groups/bp-groups-loader.php, under the function setup_nav, add a nav item:

$sub_nav[] =             array(

```
        'name'            => __( 'Private', 'buddypress' ),
        'slug'            => 'anything',
        'parent_url'      => $groups_link,
        'parent_slug'     => $this->slug,
        'screen_function' => 'groups_screen_my_groups',
        'position'        => 20,
        'user_has_access' =>  bp_is_my_profile(),
 );
```

**3.** In bp-default/members/single/groups.php, add an else to the present if:

elseif ( bp_is_current_action( 'anything' ) ) :

```
     do_action( 'bp_before_member_groups_content' ); ?> 
     <?php locate_template( array( 'members/single/groups/anything.php' ), true ); ?>
     <?php do_action( 'bp_after_member_groups_content' );
```

**4.** In bp-default/members/single/groups/ create a new file 'anything.php' and write this code to show JUST the private groups of a user:

```
  <li id="field_reg_groups_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="field_reg_groups[]" value="<?php bp_group_id(); ?>" />
    <?php bp_group_name(); ?>
  <div class="item-avatar">
    <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=50&height=50' ); ?></a>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
      <div class="item-title"><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_name(); ?></a></div>

      <div class="item-meta">
       <span class="activity"><?php printf( __( 'active %s', 'buddypress' ), bp_get_group_last_active() ); ?></span>
      </div>

      <div class="item-desc"><?php bp_group_description_excerpt(); ?>
      </div>

       <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_groups_item' ); ?>

  </div>

  <div class="action">

     <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_groups_actions' ); ?>

    <div class="meta">

       <?php bp_group_type(); ?> / <?php bp_group_member_count(); ?>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
   </li>


   <?php } 
   $i++; 
   endwhile; 
   endif; 
   else: ?>
   <p class="reg_groups_none">No selections are available at this time.</p>
```

Thats it. Follow the same for public and hidden groups, by changing the value of "anything"